# Harmonic Mean - Problem 130 in I.M. Gelfand's Algebra book

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble understanding how to approach Problem 130 in I.M. Gelfand's book. Preceding this problem he shows us the definition of the harmonic mean:

$$\frac{1}{\quad\frac{\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}}{2}\quad} = \frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}$$

He then states problem 130, which is:

*A swimming pool is divided into two equal sections. Each section has its own water supply pipe. To fill one section (using its pipe) you need $a$ hours. To fill the other section you need $b$ hours. How many hours would you need if you turn on both pipes and remove the wall dividing the pool into sections.*

So I'm having trouble understanding how to apply the harmonic mean to this problem. Any hints or guidance would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Say each section of the swimming pool is $1$ unit in volume (to simplify our lives, we are going to measure volume in half-swimming-pools, so each half is exactly one half-swimming-pool of water). The fact that the first section is filled in $a$ hours means that you are pouring water through that pipe at a rate of $\frac{1}{a}$ units per hour. Similarly, the water in the second pipe must be flowing at a rate of $\frac{1}{b}$ units per hour.

So, the water flowing into the pool through both pipes is flowing at a rate of $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\ \frac{\text{units}}{\text{hour}},$$
by adding both rates.

Now, that's the *rate* at which water is flowing. How much volume do you need to fill? How long will it take? How is it related to the harmonic mean?